# Contradictory Information in Triage Audit

Tags: bug, review-audits, triage

I was reviewing in the triage queue, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24641925) came up as an audit. It supposedly has 0 answers, one of which was accepted. This is a clear giveaway that the question is an audit, and this is not the first time this has happened.

[image]

A question with 0 answers that has an accepted answer? Please let me know if this discrepancy is left in on purpose, but I think that it should be fixed.

Comment: I think I asked something similar one time. The short answer basically was giveaways that questions are audits don't matter because the point is the audits are not for people who notice dead giveaways that it's an audit. I personally think it would still be a better audit system if this weren't the case, but I don't make the rules...